# How to make a div that doesn't resize itself

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 64 students. I want to print a student transcript for each student on one page.I have different number of subjects for different classes. When I resize my div for 12 subjects, it fits perfectly thus printing 64 pages but when the subject reduces, it prints lesser pages as the next student details spills on the previous student. Is there a way to set each div to fully occupy one page by default whether the content is small or big?

Comment: Without code it is impossible to see what is going wrong

Comment: One student per one page and 64 pages overall, or one student per one **window**, and single page?

Comment: Its seen you want us to make for you the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) property on your `div`, you can force a page break to occur before that element when printing your website, like so:

```
.student {
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

This will not work on an empty `div`, but that does not apply to your case from the sound of it.